# Interacting with Safari and Apple Pay modal

Tags: javascript, python, testing, automation, testcafe

I am trying to figure out the **best** way to handle automation of the Apple Pay modal window that appears in Safari.

The modal window is not part of the DOM.  However, I believe that there are JavaScript functions that can be accessed in order to interact with it.  I'm just really confused as to how to do this within TestCafe and JavaScript (I'll admit my JS is lacking!)

[image]

Comment: Can you maybe provide a bit more context as to why you "*believe that there are JavaScript functions that can be accessed in order to interact with it*"? Don't you feel that if there were methods you could leverage to interact with this modal, it'd be an extreme security risk?

Comment: Why a 'Security Risk'?  I just need to be able to 'click' on the Shipping/Contact places...some manual interaction MIGHT be needed for like FaceID or ThumbprintID...IDK

Answer (score 0):

The modal Apple Pay window is the OS related feature that runs via a js API. It cannot be automated. Could you please clarify why you need to automate OS related features?

Comment: We have seen a lot of different issues in Shipping/Billing addresses, along with the Pay total being calculated.  The address that is coming back from OS js API causes issue within our system and thus causes transactions to be incorrect...

Comment: I do not know if there are JS functions that allow you to manipulate this window. If they exist, you can use them in TestCafe. It allows you to run your custom js code using the ClientFunctions mechanism. Please refer to the docs: [https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/).